# Laravel. Get the result after a raw update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

```php
$user->update([
    'rating' => DB::raw('rating + 1'),
    'point'  => DB::raw('point + 1'),
    'money'  => DB::raw('money + 5'),
]);
```

If we now turn to the money field ($user->money), the expression will be returned

```php
'money' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression)
          protected 'value' => string 'money + 5'
```

Is it possible to get a new value, for example, money, without turning to the database again?

Comment: From you update code,are you trying to increment the values by the number? If so, is there a reason you are using `DB:raw()` to do this?

Comment: Can you not just do `$user->money += 1 [...]` then `$user->save()`?

Comment: increment executes a separate query to the database for each field
the more fields the more requests
raw query executes 1 query to DB, regardless of the number of changed fields

Comment: $user->money += 1  
I consider such a query not very correct, after receiving the user, the field can be changed elsewhere, and an incorrect result can be written to the database

Comment: @Visavi I'm not following your thoughts with that? Can you clarify?

Comment: for example, I received a user object, he has 500 coins, at this moment the user is writing off money, another process, 100 coins were written off
I have the same value in my object (500 coins)
if money + = 1 is executed, the value 501 will be written to the database
You can of course do all this in a transaction.

Comment: All of the above scenario you mentioned can be done through object For ex: you've a user object `$user` you update it property with 1 `$user->money +=1` you hadn't executed your query but your object is updated with `501`. Now when you execute your query thorugh `$user->save()` you save the data into db and you have new value without doing another query because value is saved into local object.

Comment: @Visavi if DB is getting updated and if you wish to have the new value instantly, you will have to query again to see if it changed. You can have periodic calls if you like.

Comment: @saad-suri

        $user1 = User::query()->find(1);
        // 500 coins;

        // other proccess for example, a cron job
        $user2 = User::query()->find(1);
        $user2->money -= 100;
        $user2->save();


        $user1->money += 5;
        $user1->save();
        // 505 coins

Comment: @Visavi this 505 is worng answer right you need 405 ?

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta No, I do not need it, I'm just trying to explain that this method without a transaction is not correct.

Comment: @Visavi could you plz explain one more time what exactly you want.

Comment: I have many fields that need to be changed, and also get a new value after that, with getting just the problem, the expression is returned instead of the value.

all offered options except increment not reliable
increment and decrement are reliable, but they make a separate query to the database, which does not suit me

I understand that the most optimal way if it is impossible to get the correct value without an additional request is to get the object again, for example through $user->refresh();

Answer (score 2):

go for simple.

```
$user->increment('rating',1);
$user->increment('point'); //default value is 1
$user->increment('money', 5);
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat hidden gem!

Comment: The point here is that OP doesn't wish to fire multiple queries and IIRC each call of this function will fire a separate query.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$user->update([
    'rating' => $user->rating + 1,
    'point'  => $user->point + 1,
    'money'  => $user->money + 5,
]);
```

or

```
$user->rating = $user->rating + 1;
$user->point = $user->point + 1;
$user->money = $user->money + 1;
$user->save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overthinking this, you can simply do the following:

```
$user->rating += 1;
$user->point += 1;
$user->money += 5;
```

Then run,

```
$user->save();
```

and thereafter, when you access the above properties, it should show the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$user->rating += 1;              $user->rating = $user->rating + 1;
$user->point += 1;     or        $user->point = $user->point + 1;
$user->money += 5;               $user->money = $user->money + 5;
```

as mentioned in previous answer

Also you can do this too if you need sum result

```
$data = ['rating' => $user->rating + 1,
          'point'  => $user->point + 1,
          'money'  => $user->money + 5 ];

$user->update($data);
```

it will give you same data in array format.